# Join two tables on a column mix with ids and space

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

how do you write a SQL statement in SQL server 2008R2 to join two tables on a column that has space?
I am getting the error "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

e.g. Table1

```
[id | value | t2id]
  1 |   a   |  1
  2 |   b   |  
  3 |   c   |  2
```

Table2

```
[id | value]
  1 |   d
  2 |   e
  3 |   f
```

Result

```
[id | value | t2id | id | value]
  1 |   a   |  1   |  1 |   d
  2 |   b   |      |null| null
  3 |   c   |  2   |  2 |   e
```

It is a left join to show all values from Table1, but the t2id column has ids from Table2 and spaces. Joining the two tables directly gave me the above error.

Thank you

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/914fc/1

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/871e8/1

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/871e8/3

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query -

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table1, Table2
 WHERE Table1.T2id = Table2.Id
   AND Table1.T2id IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Table1.*, NULL, NULL FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.T2id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks JW for the example, which is not working http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/871e8/1

Comment: @user1589188 I think by mistake you have replied in my post instead of replying to the question comment space